# Resume the LUKS decryption process

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I've run an in-place decryption process using the following command

```
sudo cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /dev/sdb1
```

But it was interrupted (The HDD was disconnected accidentally)

Is there a way to resume the process, or should I say goodbye to my data ?

---

### More information

I was able to restore the files from about **0.1%** of the HDD using `photorec` I guess it's the part that was decrypted so far.

I've found three files in my `~/` directory

```
4.0K -rw------- 1 root root  512 Oct 14 14:45 LUKS-688fbce2-bbe8-4665-aa40-dcf0e700ffea.log
1.1M -rw------- 1 root root 1.1M Oct 14 13:18 LUKS-688fbce2-bbe8-4665-aa40-dcf0e700ffea.new
1.1M -r-------- 1 root root 1.1M Oct 14 13:18 LUKS-688fbce2-bbe8-4665-aa40-dcf0e700ffea.org
```

`.log` file content

```
# LUKS reencryption log, DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE.
version = 2
UUID = 688fbce2-bbe8-4665-aa40-dcf0e700ffea
direction = 0
mode = 2
offset = 18014535680
shift = 0
# EOF
```

When I try to unlock the device

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 hdd
Reduced data offset is allowed only for detached LUKS header.
```

When I try to run `cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt` again

```
$ cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /dev/sdb1
Enter any existing passphrase: 
No key available with this passphrase.
```

> Can you still read the header ?

```
$ cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb1

LUKS header information for /dev/sdb1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    cipher_null
Cipher mode:    ecb
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 0
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      07 59 1b 61 7d 27 fc 20 d5 25 ee 55 dd 7d 28 e0 49 3d 8e cf 
MK salt:        9f 22 d1 03 f4 71 92 09 f9 2a d2 3a 8f 23 32 51 
                38 3f 38 eb 7a a9 ab 23 fd 8a 93 4c c3 90 58 89 
MK iterations:  189410
UUID:           cafecafe-cafe-cafe-cafe-cafecafeeeee

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             3120760
    Salt:                   9b 20 06 49 58 6a 02 38 65 af f6 e1 bf 8d 1b d1 
                            f0 38 e3 7b 2a 26 63 52 16 6a b4 1a 6f 5f 10 49 
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

Comment: Can you still read the header by doing `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb1`?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I've edited my question.

Comment: Well, the manpage for `cryptsetup-reencrypt` suggests that an interrupted decryption process can be resumed as long as you have the three files that you are mentioning. But it does not give precise details on how to do that. I would try starting the decrypt process again from within the folder where the logfiles are (make sure you have sufficient rights on the files and the folder), or maybe by specifying additionally the UUID given in the logfile via the `--uuid` parameter. See `man cryptsetup-reencrypt`.